# React onClick event.target.innerHTML acting strangely

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the e.target.innerHTML of a click event on a button in React component and asign it to another constant trought setState, BUT:

1. On the first click the e.target.innerHTML is showing properly by itself but the asigned state value is undefined
2. On the second click the asigned state value is shown properly
3. If I click another button in the list - the shown value is of the previous button licked
4. If I click the new button one more time - the asigned state value is shown properly

All the component code here: https://pastebin.com/pAP32qai

```js
function categoryClickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const collection = e.target.innerHTML;
    setCurrentCollection(collection);

    console.log(e.target.innerHTML, " was clicked!");
    console.log(collection, " collection");

    console.log("Current collection is: ", currentCollection);
  }

  const listItems = category.map((category) => (
    <li key={category.name}>
      <button
        className={styles.categoryBtn}
        onClick={categoryClickHandler}
        disabled={!currentUser}
      >
        {category.name}
      </button>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div className={styles.categoryBox}>
      {currentUser && <h2>Click on a category to start the quiz!</h2>}

      {!currentUser && <h2>REGISTER to start the quiz!</h2>}
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what exactly you are trying to explain? are you talking about `console.log("Current collection is: ", currentCollection);` is not printing the expected value with respect to the button you clicked?

Comment: If yes, that's because `setCurrentCollection(collection);` is asynchronous and you might be seeing previously updated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state is getting set properly there is no issue with that. The problem is that you are reading it directly after setting the state. `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later and this makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. So how you can read the state directly after it is updated. So in your case, as you are using a functional component you can use useEffect and listen to the updates on your state.

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Current Collection : ", currentCollection);
    },[currentCollection])
```

You can check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-pond-6gwkl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) on the sandbox

Comment: @PlamenPetrov Please tick it as a correct answer if it answers your question correctly. So if anyone is coming to the question he/she would know it's already been answered.